# Docker container to run UDP multicast to outside world

Tags: docker, udp, multicast

I would like to send UDP multicast from my docker container which runs on linux machine.
I failed to see the UDP multicast packets on my other machine in the network.
I tried to use `--net=host` when I run the docker container and it worked, but I would rather not to do that only because my multicast packets.
Is it possible to expose ports for doing it?
Is it possible to create another network for multicast only (somehow?)
Do you know about any another solution here?

Thanks.

Comment: Options https://docs.docker.com/network/

Answer (score 0):

You can use `macvlan network` as in the following code:

```
docker network create -d macvlan --subnet=192.168.10.0/24 --gateway=192.168.10.1 -o parent=eno1 myvHome
```